# Someone moved vote counts delimiter a bit!

Tags: bug, design, vote-count

> [image]

:-/ Fixitplease!

Comment: Now I can't unsee it, aaaaaah!

Comment: +1 for the cute face

Comment: OMG that's it! I'm not coming back to this shabby site until that is fixed! :P

Comment: The actual vote counts are also not horizontally centered.