# The vote counts delimiter is mis-aligned in the new beta theme

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites

Seems that new design for beta sites got [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244369/someone-moved-vote-counts-delimiter-a-bit), but other way around.

> [image]

Comment: Someone pushed it too hard after your earlier report.